# Include html page in aspx - Strange outcome with Response.WriteFile()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, include

I need to include the same `html` page into several `aspx` pages. Following is my `html` page:

```
<h1>Database Enciclopedico</h1>
```

And I use the `Response.WriteFile` method to include the page in my `aspx` page:

```
<div id="header">
        <% Response.WriteFile("Header.html"); %>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when the html page is included it has several new lines and white spaces at its beginning (I can see the result when I inspect the element with Google Chrome).

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following approach:

```
<%
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Header.html");
    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    Response.Write(content);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

use HTML iframe like this:

```
    <iframe id='iframe1' name='iframe1' src='abc.html'>//also add attributes of height and width

</iframe>
```